# Internal microphone is not detected in ubuntu

Tags: alsa, microphone

I bought a new laptop and install Ubuntu. In Windows 10, the microphone normally works, but not in Ubuntu.

I was searching for a solution on forum, install `pavucontrol` and try left front microphone turn on 0, but nothing happens.
Problem is, that in "input devices" I can find only analog input, not the microphone.

`alsamixer` shows:
[image: alsa mixer window]

`aplay-l`

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC256 Analog [ALC256 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`lspci -v | grep Audio`

```
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
```

`sudo lshw -c sound`

```
*-usb:2                   
       description: Video
       product: HD WebCam
       vendor: Generic
       physical id: 7
       bus info: usb@1:7
       version: 96.18
       serial: 200901010001
       capabilities: usb-2.00
       configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
  *-multimedia
       description: Multimedia audio controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
       version: 21
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
       resources: irq:129 memory:b1128000-b112bfff memory:b1100000-b110ffff
```

See also [more information about my alsa](http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=0555ec30d7f888be63558f9558521d41c5afb35c).

Comment: what is your output of `aplay -l`? don't answer as a comment, edit your post and add it as code there!

Comment: can you also copy-paste into your questio the output of : `alsamixer`, `lspci -v | grep Audio`,  `sudo lshw -c sound`,?